# how to adjust in survival analysis in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I try to see the association between HbA1c variability and all-cause mortality estimated by
multivariable Cox proportional hazards models while adjusting for sex,  age and BMI.
I couldn't see any information about it. Can I create the model like below? Thank you for your answers.

```
library(survival)

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ HbA1c + sex + age+BMI, data =  dataSurv)
```

Comment: The lung data in the package does not even have HBA1c variable. What is your purpose?

Comment: data name is different, sorry I changed that part

Comment: See the section "Multivariate Cox regression analysis" [in this tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-proportional-hazards-model).

Answer (score 1):

You would start by creating a base model (without HbA1c) and then assessing the improvement in model fit (i.e. reduction in deviance) due to adding your covariate of major interest.

```
base.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~  sex + age+BMI, data =  dataSurv)
augmented.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ HbA1c + sex + age+BMI, data =  dataSurv)
```

I had a further thought regarding the statement that you could "see no information about the model". I hope you first looked at the output when you just typed the name of the model at the console:

```
res.cox
# and then typed ...

summary(res.cox)
```

The p-value in the output of `summary(augmented.cox)` is calculated from the score statistics but the change in deviance between the base model and the augmented model is a better measure for statistical inference. Some packages will provide an "anova" function to calculate this for you.

```
library(survival)
?anova.coxph
anova(base.cox, augmented.cox)
```